# Configuring an additonal sub login area with ASP.NET membership?

Tags: authentication, web-config, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, location

I have a main login for my client facing website configured with ASP.NET membership.

I also have a secondary login for my admin backoffice called /admin
with a login page

/admin/login.aspx

upon logging in it should direct to:

/admin/secure/

I've placed a web.config file in /admin/secure/ as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="admin" />
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My problem is I want to use .net membership to redirect back to /admin/login.aspx if un autehnicated users try and access it rather than using the top level redirect (/login.aspx) which is used for my client facing login.

**Is this possible?**

My attempt so far has been to add the following into my root level web.config file:

```
<location path="admin">
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="appTTESubAuth" path="~/admin/" loginUrl="~/admin/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120"/>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I get the following error:

> It is an error to use a section
>   registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>   beyond application level.  This error
>   can be caused by a virtual directory
>   not being configured as an application
>   in IIS.

So i tried this:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup, System.Web, Version=%ASSEMBLY_VERSION%, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=%MICROSOFT_PUBLICKEY%">
            <section name="authentication" type="System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationSection, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <!-- Other system.web sections -->
        </sectionGroup>
```

which gives me

> Section or group name 'system.web' is
>   already defined. Updates to this may
>   only occur at the configuration level
>   where it is defined

Anyone managed to do this using .net membersip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's going to be hard to get working. What I don't understand is why not use the same login page for both but add your admins to a role that none of the "regular" users have. That should be enough really.

Comment: I agree with the answer above that what you describe is probably not possible with Forms authentication.  The only way I could find to redirect to a separate login page for admin user was to move admin pages to their own application

Comment: klausbyskov, I wanted to do it like this because it looks a bit more profesional to have a seperate login area for administration.

I thought this might be the case that it's not possible. Doh, the only way I can concieve to get this to work it let it redirect to the homepage login and then check the referer path. If it came from the /admin redirect back to the admin login.